# DAX MTD minus 1 month

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a big problem with calculating Sales MTD -1 (to calculate MoM Change). I can't use TOTALMTD, because firstly my data end on 2022-02-19, totalmtd returns day from today(), and secondly I have to use RLS after that.

My measure to calculate Sales MTD is below:

```
SALES MTD = 
VAR maxcalendar = CALCULATE(MAX(_Calendar[Date]),ALL(_Calendar))
VAR y = SELECTEDVALUE(_Calendar[#Year])
VAR m = SELECTEDVALUE(_Calendar[#Month])
VAR d = DAY(maxcalendar)
VAR startdate = DATE(y,m,1)
VAR enddate = DATE(y,m,d)
RETURN
CALCULATE(
    Metrics[Sales],
    FILTER(_Calendar,
    _Calendar[Date] >= startdate && _Calendar[Date] <= enddate))
```

But I can't calculate correctly SALES MTD -1 month

My code:

```
SALES MTD -1M = 
VAR maxcalendar = CALCULATE(MAX(_Calendar[Date]),ALL(_Calendar))
VAR y = SELECTEDVALUE(_Calendar[#Year])
VAR m = SELECTEDVALUE(_Calendar[#Month])
VAR d = DAY(maxcalendar)
VAR startdate = DATE(y,m,1)
VAR enddate = DATE(y,m,d)
VAR enddateminusm = EOMONTH(enddate,-1)
VAR startdate2 = DATE(YEAR(enddateminusm),MONTH(enddateminusm),1)
VAR enddate2 = DATE(YEAR(enddateminusm),MONTH(enddateminusm),d)
VAR result = 
CALCULATE(
    Metrics[Sales],
    FILTER(_Calendar,
    _Calendar[Date]>= startdate2 && _Calendar[Date] <= enddate2))
RETURN
result
```

EOMONTH is used to get a date one month back. Why does it not working?

It returns a blank value.

[image]

Comment: CALCULATE(CALCULATE([Sales],PREVIOUSMONTH(_Calendar[Date])),DATESMTD(_Calendar[Date])

Comment: DATESMTD returns sales from all month:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the FILTER(_Calendar...) you do not change a context. And when you are trying to get dates they are not existing in the current context. That's why they are blank. Your expression:

```
CALCULATE(
    Metrics[Sales],
    FILTER(_Calendar,
    _Calendar[Date]>= startdate2 && _Calendar[Date] <= enddate2))
```

is equal to:

```
CALCULATE -- Matrix context
    CALCULATE(
             Metrics[Sales],
             FILTER(_Calendar,
             _Calendar[Date]>= startdate2 && _Calendar[Date] <= enddate2)
    )
    ,_Calendar[#Year]=SELECTEDVALUE(_Calendar[#Year])  -- comes from matrix
    ,_Calendar[#Month]=SELECTEDVALUE(_Calendar[#Month]) -- comes from matrix
)
```

Try to filter like this - `FILTER(ALL(_Calendar)...)`.
Normally, a syntax as below should work. The problem can come from RLS. Most of DATE functions can be violated by RLS https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/dateadd-function-dax. So, check you RLS and try to check if you can get the value of certain dates using simple measures.

```
VAR FirstDay = 
        DATEADD(
                FIRSTDATE(DATESMTD(_Calendar'[Date]))
                ,-1
                ,Month
        )
VAR LastDay = 
          DATEADD(
                  LASTDATE(DATESMTD(_Calendar'[Date]))
                  ,-1
                  ,Month
          )
     
VAR SetOfDates= 
        DATESBETWEEN(
                    _Calendar'[Date]
                    ,FirstDay 
                    ,LastDay
        )
RETURN 
        CALCULATE(
                  SUM(Metrics[Sales])
                  ,SetOfDates
        )
```

Comment: The second solution returns all dates, instead of dates between 2022-01-01 and 2022-01-19 for February. But, the solution with ALL inside Filter function returns correctly answers :). Thank you :)